# Matching ChromeDriver Version And Chrome Browser Version On Multiple Development Environments

Tags: angular, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am running Angular e2e tests which are run by Protractor. I have this script in my package.json as post installation script:

```
"postinstall": "cd ./node_modules/protractor && npm i webdriver-manager@latest && cd .. && ./.bin/webdriver-manager update"
```

On my local machine, currently the Chrome Browser v81 is installed. This is the latest stable version of Chrome.

However, this webdriver manager is running on ChromeDriver v83. Chrome Browser v83 is still a beta version. So that, I need to download it manually. Which is already weird, latest webdriver should match with latest stable browser version I think.

Let say I did this manually. However, this code is written for run on Jenkins. I have a Dockerfile which downloads and installs the latest chrome to a Linux machine. I cannot hardcode driver-browser version to dockerfile and package.json all the time.

```
  curl -fsS https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && add-apt-repository 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' \
  && curl -fsS https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add - \
  && add-apt-repository "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x $(lsb_release -cs) main" \
  && apt-get install -qq \
  google-chrome-stable \
```

And also, I am using MacOS, another developer is using Windows machine. So that, if I attempt to learn which chrome version is installed on the machine, I need to write different scripts for all operating systems.

How should I approach this problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: inside of your docker container try to run `google-chrome --version` let me know what it returns, I might be able help you out

Comment: output: 81.0.4044.138